# Formatar percentagem em python

Tags: python, pandas

Como devo formatar a percentagem para este exemplo?

```
import pandas as pd
flights = pd.read_csv('data/flights_until_june.csv', sep=',')
sum_null = flights.isnull().sum()
sum_null.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
total = flights.shape[0]
percentage = round(sum_null/total * 100, 2)
print(percentage)
print('{:2%}'.format(percentage))
```

Comment: Olá Ricardo, bem-vindo à comunidade da Stack Overflow em Português! Acredito que a formatação que deseja é mostrar a porcentagem com duas casas decimais com o sinal de '%' ao final?

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Basta usar o modificador `.xf` para definir quantas casas decimais você quiser, nesse caso basta substituir a letra `x` por um número inteiro. Observe que ao fazer isso ele não irá truncar o número, mas sim arrendondar ele. Já o símbolo de porcento tem que ser colocado após o fecha chaves `}` ao final do "place holder" do número.

Exemplo:

```py
>>> print('{0:.2f}%'.format(34.56634))
34.57%
```

> Note que em `'{0:.2f}%'` o `0` pode ser omitido ficando somente `'{:.2f}%'`

Answer (score -5):

```
>>> y = print('{0:.2f}'.format(34.56634), '%')
34.57 %
```

1. a expressão 2f significa dois valores flutuante (f). Então vai aparecer dois números após a virgula.
2. O ponto que aparece ao lado do .2 significa que após a virgula haverá apenas dois valores (você pode aumentar esse valor para 3f e vai aparecer 34.576
3. A expressão que esta dentro das chaves { } e tem que ficar dentro de uma string.
4. A expressão .format tem que vir após a string e mostrando que você quer formatar o número que esta dentro do parênteses. toda essa informação é separada por uma virgula. Ou seja a virgula separa uma informação da informação seguinte. O resultado de saída vai ser um valor numérico e você pode atribuir a esse valor uma unidade com uma nova virgula ou seja você vai atribuir uma nova informação que é a porcentagem mas observe que ela é uma string longo tem que vir entre suas aspas simples (ou poderia ser dupla. Isso é muito usado em cálculos quando o aluno quer mostrar na saída que o resultado é 2,24 m, ou a temperatura é 75 K.

É um código muito comum nas engenharias.

Comment: Isso está péssimo, e se um engenheiro usar esse valor de `y` numa obra o prédio cai. A função [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#print) não retorna valor. O mesmo resultado pode ser obtido com fstring: `print(f'{34.56634:.2f}%')`